# Python invalid Syntax Why?c

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax, syntax-error, spyder

Why is this invalid syntax?

```
if 0.9*x < d[o] < 1.1*x:
```

Here's the whole code

```
def phipsd(d,p):
   a=[]
   lend = len(d)
   ad=np.array(d)
   for i in range(0,9):
       for o in range(0, len(d)):
           x = (500/(2**(i))*10**-6                 
           if 0.9*x < d[o] < 1.1*x:
               c = c + p[o]
       a.append([])
       b=a[i]
              b.append(c)
```

Comment: I notice that the line prior to that one has three left parentheses, and two right parentheses. This is a problem.

Comment: Python will try and help you find your syntax error but it can be more than just that line that is causing the syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line you quoted isn't the source of your error. This line is:

```
x = (500/(2**(i))*10**-6
```

Note the mismatched parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
def phipsd(d,p):
   a=[]
   lend = len(d)
   ad=np.array(d)
   for i in range(0,9):
       for o in range(0, len(d)):
           x = (500/(2**(i))*10**-6    # Here is a SyntaxError, Because You've started 3 parentheses but terminated only 2. So, add a closing parenthesis in the right place.             
           if 0.9*x < d[o] < 1.1*x:
               c = c + p[o]
       a.append([])
       b=a[i]
       b.append(c)
```

See the comment

Comment: Thak you, all fixed :)

Comment: @Hoffi.D.. The most efficient way to thank someone who correctly answer your question on stack overflow is by giving a green checkmark  on his answer